# DSE Graph with Java Driver, how to add edges

Tags: cassandra, gremlin, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver, datastax-enterprise-graph

I want to build a graph completely with the Datastax Java Driver. I managed to insert vertices, but I have no clue how to add edges to existing vertices.

When I run the following code

```
session.executeGraph("parent = g.V().has('businessId','sys-1').next()");
session.executeGraph("child = g.V().has('businessId','sys-2').next()");
session.executeGraph("parent.addEdge('consistsOf', child)");
```

I get an exception

```
Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: No such property: parent for class: Script285
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException.copy(InvalidQueryException.java:50)
    at com.datastax.driver.dse.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:29)
    at com.datastax.driver.dse.DefaultDseSession.executeGraph(DefaultDseSession.java:77)
    at com.datastax.driver.dse.DefaultDseSession.executeGraph(DefaultDseSession.java:64)
    at de.pratho.valpro.tools.Main.main(Main.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: No such property: parent for class: Script285
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:136)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.onSet(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:179)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:173)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.access$2500(RequestHandler.java:43)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:788)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.onSet(RequestHandler.java:607)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:1012)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:935)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:318)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:304)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:318)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:304)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:318)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:304)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:263)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:318)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:304)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

When I run the gremlin statements in the gremlin_console_window it is working fine. So I think variables like `parent` and `child` are not working within a Java `DseSession`?

Unfortunately, I was not able to find much information about how to work with the Java Driver properly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you have to create it within the context of the same script, i.e:

```
DseCluster dseCluster = DseCluster.builder()
            .addContactPoint("127.0.0.1")
            .withGraphOptions(new GraphOptions().setGraphName("demo"))
            .build();
DseSession dseSession = dseCluster.newSession();
SimpleGraphStatement s = new SimpleGraphStatement(
            "def v1 = g.V(id1).next()\n" + 
            "def v2 = g.V(id2).next()\n" +
            "v1.addEdge('relates', v2)");
dseSession.executeGraph(s);
```

I think the reason for this is that these commands are just interpreted as independent gremlin queries.

I believe [this](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver-dse/1.0/supplemental/manual/graph/) set of documentation may be helpful to you.